# implement stack using C getting error : is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to implement a stack to solve parenthesis problem, but i'm getting confused with the pointers(i'm new to C)
here is my code so far:

```
typedef struct node{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
typedef struct stack{
    struct node **head;
}stack;
void push(stack *s, char c){
    node *n = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data = c;
    if(*s->head == NULL){
        n->next = *s->head;
        *s->head = n;
    }
    else{
        n->next = *s->head;
        *s->head = n;
    }
}
void pop(stack *s){
    if(s->head->next == NULL){
        *s->head = NULL;
    }
    else{
        node *temp = *s->head;
        *s->head = s->head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
bool isStringBalanced(char** sentence, int size){
    stack *s = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    *s->head = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int j = 0;
        while(sentence[i][j] != '\0'){
            switch(sentence[i][j]){
                case '(' : push(s, '('); break;
                case '[' : push(s, '['); break;
                case '{' : push(s, '{'); break;
                case ')' : 
                    if(*s->head)
                        if(*s->head->data == '(')
                            pop(s);
                        else return false;
                    else return false;
                    break;
                case ']' :
                    if(*s->head)
                        if(*s->head->data == '[')
                            pop(s);
                        else return false;
                    else return false;
                    break;
                case '}' :
                    if(*s->head)
                        if(*s->head->data == '{')
                            pop(s);
                        else return false;
                    else return false;
                    break;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(!s->head)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

when i try to run this, i get error on all the double arrows like s->head->data and s->head->next
Help me to understand how to use right double pointer
thanks.

Comment: You need to just make up your mind which syntax to use. If `s` is defined as `stack *s` and `stack` is a struct, you would use either `s->member` or `(*s).member`. Refer to the C language reference for details.

Comment: i never used (*s). i always used ->

Comment: Why is `head` a pointer-to-a-pointer?

Comment: In `stack`, I don't think you need `struct node **head;`; just a single indirection would do `struct node *head;`. Furthermore, because of this, I think you are getting confused by the two different ways to reference `head` and `next`.

Comment: When you use `s->head->next`, it would only work if head is node*, not node** like you have.

Answer (score 5):

A double pointer is a pointer to a pointer. It is useful for example when you
want that a function changes where a pointer is pointing:

```
void foo(char **str)
{
    *str = "World";
}

void bar(void)
{
    const char *x = "Hello";
    puts(x); // points to "Hello"
    foo(&x);
    puts(x); // points to "World"
}
```

This would print<sup>1</sup>:

```
World
Hello
```

A double pointer can be used for storing an array of arrays or pointers. This
can be used for example for storing matrices.

In your case, the double pointer in `stack` is not needed, it's inside an
structure. Sure you can declare it as a double pointer, but it will make live
unnecessarily harder. `head` is already inside a struct and you usually pass
the `stack` object as whole. So functions altering the pointing location of
`head` can do that without the need of a double pointer, because `head` is not
a variable, it is a member of a struct (see example below).

So you can rewrite it as:

```
typedef struct stack{
    struct node *head;
}stack;
```

Then the `push` can be rewritten as:

```
int push(stack *s, char c)
{
    node *n = calloc(1, sizeof *n);
    if(n == NULL)
        return 0;

    n->data = c;
    n->next = s->head;
    s->head = n; // see footnote 2
}
```

As for the question about `->` and `.`: `->` and `.` are used to access the
members of a struct. If the variable (or expression) is not a pointer, then you use `.`, if the
variable (or expression) is a pointer, then you use `->`. It's as simple as
that:

```
// Note these examples show only how to use -> and .

stack *s;
s->next;             // because s is a pointer
s->next->next;       // because s->next is a pointer
s->next->next->data  // because s->next->next is a pointer

stack s;
s.next;              // because s is not a pointer
s.next->next;        // because s is not a pointer, but s.next is a pointer
s.next->next->data;  // because s is not a pointer, but s.next is a pointer
                     // and s.next->next is also a pointer
```

---

**fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>A string literal (the ones in quotes) return the address of where
the sequence of characters are stored. In C a string is just a sequence of
characters that ends with the `'\0'`-terminating byte.

When you do

```
const char *x = "Hello";
```

your are **not** copying the string to `x`, you are assigning the location of
the sequence

```
base = some memory location

base
+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| H | e | l | l | o | \0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+
```

of `char`s to the pointer `x`. The value of `x` is that address `base`.

<sup>2</sup>Thanks to user [user7231](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9009404/user7231) for pointing out that in this case even
the `if(n->head == NULL)` check is not necessary. I've updated my answer using
his/hers lines. Credit goes to [user7231](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9009404/user7231).

Comment: Why rewrite push with a loop when it was perfectly fine and shorter in the original code? Also your push pushes to the end of chain, why?

Comment: @user7231 you are right, I was more focused on the double-pointer vs single-pointer than the actual meaning of the "push" in a stack. Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Instead of if-else it's better to just assign `n->next = s->head; s->head = n;`

Comment: @user7231 right again. Sometimes the fingers are faster than the brain and the examples one provides can be improved. Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer.